# How wet a hole (with rain) is too wet to put concrete anchors in?

Tags: concrete, patio, moisture, anchor, rain

A few weeks ago I drilled 1/4" holes in my patio slab to mount some ~6' tall 4x4s with post brackets and wedge anchors (for a catio - ideally able to bear the weight of jumping cats).  But I didn't insert all the anchors immediately (a few I positioned but didn't hammer) and it's rained several times with the holes exposed.  I've been assuming that I have to make sure the holes are quite dry before I put in the anchors so they don't force moisture into the crucial holding points of the concrete.  But I'd love to be wrong about that because so far it's been impossible to find a dry day when I also have the energy to thoroughly dry each hole.  (I'm disabled and every spoon expenditure leads to a cumulative risk of even more damaging procrastination, frankly.)

Naturally since I don't know a lot about concrete I'm also paranoid about unintended consequences of drying methods, like leaving cotton or paper shreds or powder residues that interfere with the fastener or going overboard with a hair dryer (if I ever get one).  It's annoying for me to access a wet vac and I doubt it's much more effective but I could do so if necessary.

There was particularly heavy rain immediately after I drilled the holes and some of them will have been fully filled with water for probably at least a few days.

On top of that it's about to rain again, and I'm trying to work out if it's worth it to plug or cover them with something (with or without trying to dry them out first), and if so how best to do that without limiting air flow and potentially making them even damper, especially after I inevitably leave them like that for a while.

So, questions:

1. Are the holes still safe to use at all?
2. How do I tell when they're dry enough to put in the anchors?
3. Any good tips or specialty swabs for drying them easily?  Any warnings of what not to do?
4. Can I let them be rained on indefinitely until I'm ready to dry them or should I try to start protecting them from further rain contact ASAP?
5. If so, how?  Bearing in mind that I am likely to procrastinate setting up anything with multiple steps and equally likely to procrastinate undoing any temporary "emergency measure."
6. For the ones where the anchors have been tightly fit in but not yet hammered, do I need to remove them and make sure the holes are dry?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would get a pair of eye goggles, close my mouth, and push a 3/16 rod down the holes fast and remove.  Then put in the anchors.

Comment: Too many questions and most are opinion based

Comment: how wet, if they're full of ice that's too wet, if they're merely flooded to the brim, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, consider what happens when it rains the day after you have gone to great lengths to dry out the holes and install the anchors in dry holes.

They get wet.

Unless you are using some sort of epoxy anchor, water is a non-issue for any mechanical anchor in concrete, at least any anchor suitable for installation outdoors (some steel anchors will rust. Those will also work fine, until they rust out/away. But they are a poor choice here, given options that are corrosion resistant.)

When you think about the overall behavior of a slab of concrete outdoors, it's a not-very-absorbent sponge, and if you're not in the desert it will be wet everywhere but the surface most of its life.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I was unsure what sealing effect the wedges might have and worried the moisture levels would be too variable if I put them in the damp, or that the concrete would be forced into prolonged contact with moisture they wouldn't otherwise.  But if all anchors let in that moisture anyway that's very comforting to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Water in the hole is inconsequential.

Install your anchors. Build what you intend to build. There is no chance of hydro lock or concrete fracture from the water in the holes.

Comment: Excellent, thank you